# User search INTERNAL ERROR JAVA API

Tags: java, userapp

I am trying to make a user search but I always get an Internal error. I am doing it with the follow parameters:

```
'{"page":2,"page_size":250,"fields":"*","filters":{"query":"login:marydice"}}'
```

My code looks like:

```
API api = new API(APP_ID,TOKEN);
UserApp.ClientOptions options = api.getOptions();
options.debug = true;
options.throwErrors = true;
api.setOptions(options);
result = api.method("user.search").parameter("page", 2)
.parameter("page_size", 250)
.parameter("fields","*").parameter("filters", 
new UserApp.Struct().parameter("query", "login:marydice")).call();
```

What am I missing? and BTW, if a performed a search without any parameters it works jsut fine. On the other hand, if a get two pages as result, how can a get the items in the second page????

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace.

Comment: There is no stacktrace, the only message a got is INTERNAL_ERROR. It looks like:

Recieved response '{"error_code":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"An internal error occurred. Please contact support at help@userapp.io for more details about this error."}'

Answer (score 0):

You should contact support as suggested by the error message.  An internal error is a sign that you have triggered some kind of bug in the API.